# Extending .net control: How to prevent HTML atttribute from rendering

Tags: asp.net, .net, gridview, custom-server-controls, servercontrols

I've written a server control that extends the standard .net Gridview control.

However, by default the standard gridview control adds a **border="0"** attribute to the html markup that it produces, and I want to prevent this attribute from being rendered by my server control.

I could probably use ScriptManager to add a bit of Javascript that removes the attribute once the page that the control sits on has loaded, but that seems a bit clunky and I was hoping that somebody could tell me how to do it cleanly by, for example, adding **this.Attributes.Remove("border");** to the PreRender event of the control or something similar (which didn't work by the way, or I wouldn't have to ask the question)

Comment: Take a look at Control Adapters.

Comment: I've had a look at the 'Css Friendly adapters' at http://www.asp.net/cssadapters/ - but this adapter, and I guess others too, override the RenderControl method and implement their own code for rendering a gridview.  It seems massive overkill just to prevent an attribute from being rendered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using a devexpress gridview so it might be a bit different, but I noticed the same thing happening, and I added

```
grid.Attributes["border"] = "";
```

to the page load event, and the border no longer rendered in html. A bit of a hack but it worked for me.

Comment: Tried that and the only effect is that rather than being rendered with border="0", the gridview was rendered with border="1".  Note that my issue is not about whether the table displays a border, but about removing the deprecated border attribute from the rendered html.

Comment: Ah, with devexpress it totally removed the border attribute, but only from the most outer tag associated with the grid. I understand your quandary, I looked into to control adapters and yes it seems like a bit much to play with just to remove an attribute, but what is the possibility instead of recreating the entire control rendering, you merely 'copy' it over to the adapter and change what you want from there?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about 'copying' it over.  I'll have to do a bit more research I think!

Comment: I found this article somewhat informative: [Extreme ASP.NET Control Adapters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163543.aspx) basically where it says "Internally, when a control is rendering, the Control base class will first check to see if there is a control adapter currently associated with the control. If there is, it will invoke the Render method of the adapter; if not, it calls the standard Render method of the control" 

so what i meant by 'copy it over' was paste pretty much all of the actual render method to the adapter render method, then just  change what you want to

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean.  I think for this case though it would be at least as easy to use javascript to remove the border attribute.  I believe that you've answered my question though, in that it seems there is no way to do what I wanted in a clean, simple and uncomplicated way.

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is set `Gridlines` to **"None"**

refer: [GridLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.gridlines.aspx) property of the `GridView`.

```
<asp:GridView GridLines="None" />
```

Ofcourse, if you want more control over the rendering, control adapters are what you are looking for.

Comment: I already use Gridlines="None", and the control is still rendered with border="0".  Are you saying that the border attribute is not rendered for you?  If so, I'd be interested to know why.  Perhaps the gridview is rendered out differently with a newer version of .net?  I'm currently using .net 3.5